# Java Ignore Exception and Continue

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to write a program that checks neighbouring entries of the matrix. Problem is the entry might be at an edge, in which case trying to get next entry will throw an exception. That's why I've added an empty catch block to ignore it, but after catch block it returns true. I want the program to check every single entry and ignore exception. I could do this with many if statements, but is there a better way?

```
private static boolean ShipSunk(char letter, int col) {
    try {
        int row = letter - 'A' + 1;
        if (
            matrix[row + 1][col].equals("O") || 
            matrix[row - 1][col].equals("O") || 
            matrix[row][col + 1].equals("O") || 
            matrix[row][col - 1].equals("O")
        ) {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {        
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You would be much better of just modifying your code so that it does not result in ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException by checking for your array length before trying to access its indexes.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS You mean for each expression I should first check if it's in the bounds of matrix and then if the expression is false?

Comment: Looks like you're programming a battleship game and game programming requires the use of lots of if statements because games have lots of "what-if" scenarios.

Comment: In other words, you're not handling an exceptional situation. You're handling an edge-case of your general algorithm. Which means you should handle it explicitly.

Comment: Yes a bounds check is much faster than repeated exceptions. That said, "flat code" would let you check to see if the index is _out of bounds_, and then return a default (e.g. `false`) in that case. Then you can carry along with the rest of your logic.

Comment: Exceptions should be used for exceptional situations. An entity sitting at the last row/column of a table isn't that. Thus: do not use exception to control your logic then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this...

```
private static boolean ShipSunk(char letter, int col) {
    int row = letter - 'A' + 1;
    if (squareEqualsO(row + 1, col) ||
        squareEqualsO(row - 1, col) ||
        squareEqualsO(row, col + 1) ||
        squareEqualsO(row, col - 1)
    ) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private static boolean squareEqualsO(int row, int col) {
    if ((row >= matrix.length) || (row < 0)) {
        return false;
    } else if ((col >= matrix[row].length) || (col < 0)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return matrix[row][col].equals("O");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can continue if you are in a `for` loop:

```
private static boolean ShipSunk(char letter, int col) {
    int row = letter - 'A' + 1;
    int r = 2;
    int c = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        try {
            if (matrix[row + r % 2][col + c % 2].equals("O")) {
                return false;
            }
        } catch  (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {        
            continue;
        } finally {
            r -= 1;
            c -= 1;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The sequence of `r` is `[2, 1, 0, -1]`, then, the sequence of `r % 2` is `[0, 1, 0, -1].`

The sequence of `c` is `[1, 0, -1, -2]`, then, the sequence of `c % 2` is `[1, 0, -1, 0]`.

Thus, the sequence of `(r % 2, c % 2)` is `[(0, 1), (1, 0), (0, -1), (-1, 0)]`

You can check all neighbors through the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually trying to solve two problems inside of one function - 1) validating the input 2) checking if something was hit. Therefore you're doing better using one function per problem. If you're knowing upfront the limits of your grid, check if the input is inside the range. A basic approach could roughly look like this:

```
private boolean isInputValid(char letter, int col) {
    if(col < 0 || col > MAX_COL) return false;
    if(letter > MAX_LETTER || letter < MIN_LETTER) return false;
}

private static boolean ShipSunk(char letter, int col) {
    if(isInputValid(letter,col) {
        /* check if hit */
    } else {
        /* React to invalid input; e.g. count it as always miss */
    }
}
```

There are other, also better approaches - like throwing a `new IllegalArgumentException("your error message")` for an invalid coordinate. But this is something you should consider how to approach upfront.

P.S.

Please remember, that convention says you should pick lowercase names for your functions. You can save yourself and basically everyone you will be working with ever a lot of headaches.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I usually use lowerCamelCase (wrote big S by accident), I've read that that's the convention.

Comment: I already check for valid inputs beforehand, meaning that rows and cols are in the matrix bounds. What produces array exception is the +- 1. So your method allows for col == 0 as valid input, but it would produce an error.

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding. Would go with Zack Macomber's answer, then.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. This is how I've rewritten my code:

```
private static boolean ShipSunk(char letter, int col) {
        int row = letter - 'A' + 1;

        if (row + 1 < matrix.length) {
            if (matrix[row + 1][col].equals("O")) return false;
        }
        if (row > 0) {
            if (matrix[row - 1][col].equals("O")) return false;
        }
        if (col + 1 < matrix[0].length) {
            if (matrix[row][col + 1].equals("O")) return false;
        }
        if (col > 0) {
            if (matrix[row][col - 1].equals("O")) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

This is not as sophisticated as other answers, but it's simple and it works correctly (I think).